# suppress legend from specific geom in multiple geom plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot (below) that I am trying to control the legend for. The trouble is that I have both `geom_line(aes(linetype = season))` and `geom_bar(aes(linetype = season))`. I'd like to display the legend for the `geom_line` (as in plot 1 below) rather than the legend for the `geom_bar` (as in plot 2 below).

If I try using `scale_linetype(guide = F)`, it turns off the legend for both. Is there a way to display the legend for the `geom_line` linetype but not the `geom_bar` linetype? Below is the code to produce the plots.

Why? Ultimately I would like the outline of the bars to match the lines, with a nicely displayed legend. As you can see plot 2 is almost there but the legend is, well, illegible

```
# code for plot 1
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = temp, aes(pos, res, linetype = season)) +
  geom_bar(data = temp2, aes(depth, res, fill = season), 
           stat = "identity", position = "dodge", color = "black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "black"), guide = F) 

# code for plot 2
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = temp, aes(pos, res, linetype = season)) +
  geom_bar(data = temp2, aes(depth, res, linetype = season, fill = season), 
           stat = "identity", position = "dodge", color = "black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "black"), guide = F)
```

[image: Plot 1]

[image: Plot2]

Comment: Try `show_guide = FALSE`.

Comment: Yup, that's the stuff. Can't mark this as answered by joran as it's a comment. Thanks!

Comment: Go ahead and write the answer yourself, then you can mark it as answered, and get the rep too.

Answer (score 2):

Answered by joran below in a comment. Used show_guide in the geom_bar call, code shown below

```
# plot 3
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = temp, aes(pos, res, linetype = season)) +
  geom_bar(data = temp2, aes(depth, res, linetype = season, fill = season), 
           stat = "identity", position = "dodge", color = "black",
           show_guide = F) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "black"))
```

[image: plot 3]